# LTspice: conditions values measurement in error log automatically

Tags: ltspice, measurement, error

I am trying to measure automatically values according to another value on the schematic (.meas values in the log error).

Here you can see what I would like :

[image]

In this case I want in the spice error log:

When V1(Vs_aop)>15V,
read I1(Rsh)=5.927A,
save value in lor error

When V2(Vs_aop)>15V,
read I2(Rsh)=5.936A,
save value in lor error

... ect

I try to use .meas with WHEN condition but it doesn't work :

.meas TRAN Ich_min WHEN I(Rsh)=V(vs_aop)>15

[image]

Comment: Why use log , when the slope is linear due to Bulk resistance of transistor and obvious with various bias currents.  If it is a FET then it is RdsOn, if it is a BJT then it is Rce inversely proportional to input bias and limited by size or power rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only `when` is used then the implied form is `find time when`, or `find freq when`, which means the result is `time` or `freq`. You need to write the full syntax and explicitely choose the desired quantity to measure, here `I(Rsh)`:

```
.meas Ich_min find I(Rsh) when V(Vs_aop)=15
```

It looks like you're using a `.step` card, so there's no need to use `Ichmin1, Ich_min2, Ich_min3, ...`. Here's a quick test:

[image: test]

Comment: Thank you for tour help, It works well but with "=" rather than ">".  

**.meas Ich_min find I(Rsh) when V(Vs_aop)=15**

Comment: @George Oops, corrected. The picture shows it right, though.